# Show virtual keyboard when text box in any application is clicked C#

Tags: c#, triggers, textbox, keyboard, virtual

I'm making a c# windows application that will make it possible to fully control your windows computer via a gaming controller only. Right now I'm done with mouse control coding and I'm testing for bugs. What I want next is to create a virtual keyboard which shows up when a text box in any application is clicked. For example, the android keyboard which only appears when you need it. I have searched and the only thing I have found so far is how to call a function only when the text box is in the same Form. My question is if there is a way to make a listener when a textbox is clicked for all open programs. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score -1):

You should send the code or integer between forms when user click on the textbox using code like :

```
public string _label3
    {
        get { return label3.Text; }
    }
```

you write value and send it to other form then receive it using set method.

```
public string _label3
    {
        set { return label1.Text; }
    }
```

Using timer to watch coming value all time or check for label1.text then, when u receive this value
using this code to open virtual Keyboard.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("osk.exe");
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply Mahmoud but I don't quite get your answer. For example, how can I use your code to check if a textbox in google chrome or some other browser has been pressed and a virtual keyboard is needed to type in?

Comment: I think he thought I meant detecting the textbox only in your own application and then start the windows builtin virtual keyboard. I'm also still searching for a solution to detect a textbox in any running program.